# show urls only for webpages using bibtex and urlbst

Tags: bibtex, urls, urlbst

I used `urlbst` package to modify a `.bst` file for URL inclusion. All worked good, but if I want the url only for the webpages, how should i modify the `.bst`?

From what I read the response should be in this function:

```
FUNCTION {output.url}
{ url empty$
'skip$ 
{ new.block 
  format.url output
  format.lastchecked output
}
  if$
}
```

But i didn't managed to modify it.
Can some one point me to the right modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the definition of the function with the following

```
FUNCTION {output.url}
{
type$ "webpage" =
  {
    { url empty$
    'skip$ 
    { new.block 
      format.url output
      format.lastchecked output
    }
      if$
    }
  }
  { skip$ }
  if$
}
```

The code above puts the type of the current entry on the stack, and check whether the type is `webpage`, if the comparison is successful it executes the old procedure, otherwise it does nothing.